# Sequential channeling in Node Editor (no PBR workflow)

Tags: node-editor, masking

I'm trying to make a functional sequential channeling/masking without any external media. To make my point clear, I made this quick `.blend` where a traffic light goes to red > yellow > green when the input value rises.

**This is the effect I've got so far:**

[image: so far]

**This is my node setup:**

[image]

**And this is the desired output:**

[image: desired effect]

I know that in a `PBR` workflow I could just make an image for channeling/masking the output colors via UV mapping, but I wonder if I can achieve the same effect without external data

**Objective:**

- Achieve the desired sequential effect with different color output on each element (see example above)

**Rules:**

- No external media or UVs for channeling/masking (PBR workflow)
- No external add-ons or plug-ins
- No animation/keyframe use

**Extra points for:**

- Optimizing node setup
- Finding and explaining a better way to achieve the desired effect
- Is there a binary value input? like an ON/OFF for each individual element instead of setting a `math` conditional by numeric values?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit: here's the original `.blend` file**
[image]

Comment: Nice topic :) BTW Isn't that like only one light should lights at a time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *"texture coordinate"* input node and a *"color ramp"*.

The X output is between 0 and 1. So if we split the color ramp in three constant steps at 0, 0.3333 and 0.6666 we'll have the color we want for the good disk.

For the grey part, we just compare the input value (0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3) to X clamped into 0 and 0.3.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nicely done and way more elegant :).

Comment: @JachymMichal, thanks... have UV yours as the OP said "no UVs"... ; )

Comment: Yeah, I must've missed that part :).

Comment: This works and meets the question requirements in a very elegant and simple way, I'm voting this as the solution to the question, thank you for helping! :)

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't help noticing an unsightly *wipe* in @lemon's answer, so here's a variation on it that *switches*.

[image]

..I'm sure this is what he meant ..

[image]

Comment: Certainly, but he said "No animation/keyframe use", so considered this does not matter...

Comment: @lemon .. Just kidding, I would not have thought of your way in a hurry :)

Comment: unsightly... I didn't even know that word 5 minutes ago : )

Comment: This works and meets the question requirements very well. It's a little bit weird those value increments, but thank you for helping with this variation and reaching the objective! :)

Comment: @ermac .. a couple more nodes would set the values to whatever you like :)  I'm releived you accepted lemon's. this is basically his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a Gradient texture with a UV map to your setup.

[image]

1. Create a UV map for the traffic lights. (UV > Project from view)
2. Add a *Texture Coordinate > Gradient texture > Color Ramp* for each phase
3. The ColorRamp (set to Constant) controls which lights are on/off during the phase

Connect it to your current setup.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works although it doesn't meet the question requirements, thank you for the alternative approach :)

Comment: You're right, I should learn to read more carefully :). Good luck with your project.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your wishes and good luck as well!

Answer (score 3):

After the good answers and suggestions, I've made my own answer with some additions to whoever wants more features with this workflow idea.

**Here's an optimized output** (inspired by all the proposals received):

[image: optimized output]

**And the optimized node setup:**

[image: optimized node setup]

---

**Explanation:**

Four `math` nodes in total function as the masking factor and it's suitable for extending the object count and its values. To achieve this, the light lamps are now individual geometries (they are not into the same mesh group) and they were assigned with a different `Object Index` (`Object Properties` > `Relations` > `Pass Index`) to each one. Having now a unique index identification, it's now easier to control which element (or elements) changes sequentially when the value input increases.

**Usage:**
You can now add more mesh elements and features to change sequentially

- Separate the mesh or add a new geometry
- Delegate an `Object Index` number to each geometry
- Add an extra color in the `ColorRamp` or any feature you like
- Change the `Modulo` value to match all the Index numbers
- Subtract 1 Index number from the total in the `Divide` node

By following these steps you can now control the sequential output using only **just 1 click** with no UVs or external masking media :)

**Extra idea:**

- You can delegate the same `Object Index` to different geometries if you want them to have the same output when it's needed (for example: making the 3-2-1 countdown all in red and the GO! light in green). It's not necessary to have 4 colors to achieve this, you can just put Red and Green color in the `ColorRamp` and delegate the same `Object Index` value to each 3-2-1 sequence. Don't forget to update the `Modulo` and `Divide` values according to the total Index values.

---

Hope you find this useful and I hope you learned new things as I did today. **New suggestions and alternatives are always welcome.**

[image]