# how do you change material during animation

Tags: animation, materials

ok so im making something that has an on-off switch and to start the animation i want the switch to move, go from red to green, and then turn. on, i've gotten the movement down pat, but idk how to get it ti change from red to green.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194342/sequential-channeling-in-node-editor-no-pbr-workflow/194386#194386

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Nodes, you could use a Mixshader and animate the Value to change the material: 0 for one material and 1 for the other.[image]